# Can SpringBoot be use for Backend application?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, cron

One of the Spring framework advantage is dependency injection. Many had used SpringBoot for providing REST Web Services.

Read up and notice there are Scheduler and CommandLineRunner for SpringBoot, could we using SpringBoot for backend type of application to replace the usual standalone java program while making use of SpringBoot advantage (Dependency Injection)
- Cron Job (Execute and stop running)
- Long Running Process

One of the main thing I am looking into is to use annotation such as Spring Configuration, Spring Data JPA and other technology in backend application.

Answer (score 1):

Of course!

I used spring boot to back CLI projects, DB access projects and more.

Spring boot is very modular. It works by providing auto-configuration based on your maven/gradle imports. If you don't import `starter-web`/`starter-jersey` or any other `starter` that is for the web/rest api, the auto-configuration for this resources won't be triggered and you can basically enjoy all the power of spring boot to support your needs

Answer (score 0):

Definitely,
Spring boot is not a separate framework.It reduces the configuration difficulties when you using spring framework. Spring boot provides a Rapid Application Development using without complex configuration including your dispatcher servlet, XML file for database connectivity and configuration files. You can use spring boot for back-end development. Simply says you can do everything what you does in spring MVC without any complex configuration. If you are using spring boot , You can configure your database details in application.properties file. I am adding one of two links for proper reading,

https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/ ,
 https://dzone.com/articles/why-springboot